# Some errors in flash AS3 game, almost completed with lot of effort and help received

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, error-handling

First I really want to thank you for all the help you have given me so far, since I did not know anything about AS3 (basics gotoAnd stuff only) I came to Stackoverflow searching for some code already made but I was encouraged by some members to make the code by myself, now after almost 2 weeks and thanks to a lot of great people my soccer penalty kick game is almost finished, I really love this place.

I know I have to work on some collisions and other stuff since currently the game is not the best (remember I’m just a newbie), but Unfortunately while checking the game functioning by playing it over and over again, I have found the following:

1-  When you get 3 fails, then game is over and a play again button appears after some animation, you click on it and everything seems to be fine, but when you continue playing the second time you reach 3 fails, when you click the button a new cursor appears??? Please help
2-  I tried millions of times to make the ball move with speed and to animate its trajectory but was unable to make it, any help on this will be highly appreciated. I have speed variables and gravity but I didn’t know how to use them

3- I'm getting a actionscript error related to a removeChild, I tried many times removing some lines but I´m unable to fix it.

4- I'm using too many timers, I don't know if this is recommendable.

Here is the .fla file https://rapidshare.com/files/1702748636/kicks.fla just in case anybody want to try the game (this is really simple since it is my 1st AS project) and want to help me with the code and help me improving the game, and here is the code if somebody does not need to get into the file (I know this place is full of really smart people), once I finish it I know I will be able to do a lot of stuff with AS3.

---

```
  var score:Number;
  var angle:Number;
  var speed:Number;
  var cursor:MovieClip;
  var failed:Number;
  var ballRotation:Boolean = false;
  function initializeGame( ):void
  { 

        ball.x = 296.35;
        ball.y = 353.35;
score=0;
failed=0;
cursor = new Cursor();

addChild(cursor);
cursor.enabled = true;
Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
  }


  function dragCursor(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
cursor.x = this.mouseX;
cursor.y = this.mouseY;
  }

  initializeGame();
  var mouse = this.Mouse;





  function kick(evt:Event)
  {
    removeChild(cursor);

pateador_mc.play();

var timer:Timer = new Timer(500,1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayedAction);
timer.start();
function delayedAction(e:TimerEvent)
{
    moveBall();
}
  }
  speed=-100000;
  var ease:int = 100;
  var gravity:Number = 0.5;
  function moveBall()
  { 
var targetX:Number = mouseX;
var targetY:Number = mouseY;
var angle = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX);
ball.x =  mouseX + Math.cos(angle);
ball.y =  mouseY + Math.sin(angle) ;
ballRotation = true;
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);

if (ballRotation==true)
{


  keeper.gotoAndStop(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * keeper.totalFrames));
  ball.play();


}

   if (ball.hitTestObject ( keeper)){
      ball.y=keeper.x-ball.height- ball.width;
    trace ("Tomela");

}

if   (ball.hitTestObject(goalie) && ball.y>69 /*&& ball.y<178 && ball.X>139 && ball.x<466*/)
{

    gol_mc.play();
    score ++;
    showScore();
    var timer3:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
    timer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayedAction3);
    timer3.start();
    function delayedAction3(e:TimerEvent)
    {
        ball.x = 296.35;
        ball.y = 353.35;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
                addChild(cursor);
                keeper.gotoAndStop(1);

    }

}

else
{ 
    fails_mc.play();
     failed++;
    var timer2:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
    timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayedAction2);
    timer2.start();
    function delayedAction2(e:TimerEvent)
    {
        ball.x = 296.35;
        ball.y = 353.35;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
            addChild(cursor);
            keeper.gotoAndStop(1);

    }

    trace(failed);


   if (failed==3) {
       gameFinished();


       trace("YOU LOST");



       }
}
  function showScore():void{
goles_txt.text ="" +score;

}
  trace (score);

    function gameFinished(){
 gameOver.play ();
 stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
   timer2.stop();
           Mouse.show();

            this.mouseX=cursor.x ;
             this.mouseY=cursor.y;

           again_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playAgain);


  }

  function playAgain():void{
        gameOver.gotoAndPlay(31);
        fails_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
        keeper.play();


var timer4:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
    timer4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, delayedAction3);
    timer4.start();
    function delayedAction3(e:TimerEvent)
    {
    initializeGame();




}
  }

  }
```

---

I’ll really appreciate it guys , I promise I won’t be bothering again for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/3.
Problem 1 & 3 are the same problem.   Looks like your trying to remove the cursor from the stage (removeChild) every click (so it will error after the first click because it's no longer a child of anything).  Your adding it back on your delayedAction2 which doesn't run unless your hit test is true and only after 3 seconds.  On initialize game you create a whole new cursor and add that to the stage which is why you get a duplicate after the first game.

Rather than removeChild the cursor, it might better to just set it's visibility to false/true and only create it once.

1. You'll need to use an EnterFrame handler, or timer, or tween for this.  I can post an example later.
2. I can't figure out why you're using timers at all or need to delay your functions, except maybe to allow time for the kick animation?

You're code is very disorganized, naming functions things like 'delayedAction' is bad as it doesn't really tell you anything about the purposed of the function.  You also have way too much functions inside of other functions.   Here is a **quick** refactoring of your code I've done to hopefully teach a few things.  I've also added the tween for the ball animation.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var score:Number;
var cursor:MovieClip;
var failed:Number;
var ballRotation:Boolean = false;

var ballTweenX:Tween;
var ballTweenY:Tween;

var targetCursor = new Cursor(); //only want one of these and you want it to exist the whole time so keep out here.

addChild(targetCursor);


initializeGame();

function initializeGame( ):void
{ 
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);

    ball.x = 296.35;
    ball.y = 353.35;
    score=0;
    failed=0;

    targetCursor.visible = true;
    Mouse.hide();
}


function dragCursor(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    targetCursor.x = this.mouseX;
    targetCursor.y = this.mouseY;
}

function kick(evt:Event)
{
    //removeChild(targetCursor); 
    targetCursor.visible = false; 
    pateador_mc.play();

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick); //move this here, because you don't the option kick again while already kicking
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor); //added this, you probably don't want the target moving after the click...
    setTimeout(moveBall, 500);//cleaner and more efficient than using a timer for a one time delayed call.
}

function moveBall()
{ 
    var targetX:Number = mouseX;
    var targetY:Number = mouseY;
    var angle = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX);

    targetX =  mouseX + Math.cos(angle);
    targetY =  mouseY + Math.sin(angle) ;

    ballRotation = true;

    ballTweenX = new Tween(ball, "x", null, ball.x, targetX, .3, true);
    ballTweenY = new Tween(ball, "y", null, ball.y, targetY, .3, true);

    ballTweenY.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, ballTweenDone,false,0,true);

    if (ballRotation==true)
    {
        keeper.gotoAndStop(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * keeper.totalFrames));
        ball.play();
    }
}

function stopBallTween():void {
    ballTweenX.stop();
    ballTweenY.stop();
}

function ballTweenDone(e:TweenEvent):void {
    if (ball.hitTestObject ( keeper)){
        ball.y=keeper.x-ball.height- ball.width;
        trace ("Tomela");
    }

    if   (ball.hitTestObject(goalie) && ball.y>69 /*&& ball.y<178 && ball.X>139 && ball.x<466*/)
    {
        gol_mc.play();
        score ++;
        showScore();
    }else
    { 
        fails_mc.play();
        failed++;
        trace(failed);

        if (failed==3) {
           gameFinished();
           trace("YOU LOST");  
           return; //added this because you don't want the rest of this function running if it's a game over
        }
    }

    setTimeout(resetShot, 3000); //you had the code I put in resetShot repeated twice

    trace(score);
}

function resetShot():void {
    ball.x = 296.35;
    ball.y = 353.35;
    targetCursor.visible = true;
    keeper.gotoAndStop(1);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
}

function showScore():void{
    goles_txt.text ="" +score;  
}

function gameFinished(){
    gameOver.play();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kick);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCursor);
    Mouse.show();

    //this.mouseX=cursor.x ;
    //this.mouseY=cursor.y;  //These are read only properties, your can't set the mouse position...

    again_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playAgain);
}

function playAgain(e:Event = null):void{
    gameOver.gotoAndPlay(31);
    fails_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    keeper.play();

    setTimeout(initializeGame, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Hey LondonDrugs, man I'm more than grateful, thanks a lot for taking the time to review my code and to prepare such a detailed and explanatory response, you are a a kind person indeed.  I will study your code and will learn a lot from it without a doubt. I tested it and everything is working properly, I will work a little bit on  the hitTest stuff since even if the keeper touches the ball the goal is achieved, but you already helped me in an amazing way, will work around trying not to mess your neat job. Thanks again my friend, I owe you big time pal!

Comment: Hi London_Drugs, one last question pal and everything will be ready to go, I played a little bit with the hitTestObject when ball collides with the keeper but I was unable to make the ball stop and avoid the goal, made several changes but was unable to make it. Is there a way to stop the ball when it hits the keeper? I would need to stop the tween at that point I guess, is it right? I'll truly appreciate your last enlightenment my friend.